# How much time computer can last without power?

Tags: power-supply, capacitor

I got curious what if my power power was cut off by some amount of time, say 1/10 second, will computer be still working? I think so instinctly but not sure. Is there a way of telling how long will it last? I use [P650B](https://www.gigabyte.com/Power-Supply/Power-Supply#kf) power supply.

**EDIT**

And what are the edge cases? Between working and not working. will the programs running on it be partially damaged?

Comment: I've had lights flicker on and off and clocks reset, but not had the computer be bothered. 100ms is probably too long.  No telling because power supply does not tell you power consumption.

Comment: your question is like this one ... `I'm using Pirelli P Zero tires. If I drive around a bend at 100 km/h will I slide into the ditch?`

Comment: Laptop or desktop? Laptop with dead battery? Desktop was really short which is one reason UPS was/is popular...

Comment: @jsotola Not in my late lamented MR2 Supercharger, usually :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is called hold-up time. This is the amount of time the power supply can sustain regulation after loss of input power.

Manufacturers provide this data in the power supply specification. Here is an example from Corsair.

[image: hold-up time]

[source](https://www.corsair.com/corsairmedia/sys_master/productcontent/corsair-psu-spec-table.pdf)

This is the minimum guaranteed hold-up time from a loss of all input power. In reality you can sustain regulation for longer depending on the specific AC power conditions.